# SignalR and HTTPS

Tags: https, signalr

Does SignalR work with HTTPS?

I have a site on SSL and I want to use SignalR.
Is it possible?

If so, do I need to write something different / add configuration?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes it does! If you're talking about self host:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/how-to-walkthrough-using-httplistener-or-http-server-unmanaged-code-c-as-an-ssl-simple-server

If you're using IIS:
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

SSL is a host concern, not really related to SignalR.

Comment: so SignalR will work over HTTPS ? my site is ASP.NET 4 mvc, hosted on the web.

Comment: Here's another more detailed link for how to set up SSL for SignalR with self-hosting: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/Sep/23/Hosting-SignalR-under-SSLhttps