# SIgnalR not running over Https

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Problem is, in production the webapp is delivered over HTTPS and the signalR hub is delivered over classic HTTP (e.g. http://test.com/SignalRNotificationH) and, as expected, most modern browser throw a mixed-content warning and refuse to talk to signalR.

My questions are:

1) Is there a way to avoid the mixed-content warning by code?

2) Would it be worth to build a self-hosted http server supporting HTTPS? And, if so, will the browser talk to a client on https://test.com/SignalRNotificationH with some self-signed certificate?

Client Page Code is:

```
<title>SignalR Echo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js"></script>
```

```
    function htmlEncode(value) {

        return $("<div/>").text(value).html();
    }
    function addMsg(msg) {

        $("#messages").append("<li>" + htmlEncode(msg) + "</li>");
    }
    $(function () {

        $("#join").click(function () {

            var connection = $.connection("https://test.com/SendMessage", "groupname=" + $("#name").val(), true);

            connection.received(function (data) {

                addMsg(data);
            });
            connection.error(function (err) {

                addMsg("Error: " + err);

            });
            addMsg("Connecting...");

            connection.start(function () {

                addMsg("Connected.");

                $("#send").click(function () {

                    connection.send($("#msg").val());

                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Name:</span></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="name" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Join" id="join" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Message:</span></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="msg" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Send" id="send" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
```

`

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Global.asax protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Routing setting for 
            RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<SignalRConnection>("SendMessage", "/SendMessage", new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true });
        }

Comment: move it to question, also client part

Comment: You should just not mix http and https - that's bad practice and the Browsers are totally right to warn about that.

Comment: If I change "https ://test.com/SendMessage" to "http ://test.com/SendMessage" it is working

Comment: possible duplicate [signalr-and-https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336338/signalr-and-https)

Comment: Sorry my question is how can i fixed it

Comment: I have tried  signalr-and-https but it's not working for me