# Client cannot connect to signalR server

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I get an error when my client tries to connect to my SignalR server,
I'm using signlR 2.0.3 the request works when I use Http and it failes when I use Https

the error I get is

> "An error occurred while sending the request"

and the inner exception is

```
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
```

Comment: There is some good info on signalR and HTTPS here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336338/signalr-and-https

Comment: Are you using a self signed certificate?

Comment: Yes I'm using a self signed certificate, and IIS is configure to use it

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Server is running on localhost with self made SSL Cert (which resolves with localhost but complains with the server IP / loop back address, 127.0.0.1) you have to choose Advance/Proceed kind of thing from the browser to see the server web app. Now when I change IP address of the Hub Connection URL in the win form client with 'localhost' it works fine. So, I think, making sure of the URL domain has correct SSL cert installed on the server should help anyone looking for help on this.