# SignalR: how to implement signing or encryption of requests/responses

Tags: .net, security, encryption, signalr

I'm looking for input around options to implement signing/encryption of data being transferred by SignalR. SSL may not be an option for us due to deployment environments which are not in our control.

What would be the recommended way to do this within the SignalR framework?

We are aware that it is possible to build a HubPipelineModule which could be injected into the process, however this module doesn't appear to have access to the incoming request stream.

We could encrypt or sign the data before passing to SignalR, and pass the encrypted data (or plain text plus HMAC) to the server as string parameters, but feel it would be cleaner if we could utilise the pipeline model to handle it within the framework itself.

Any suggestions? Are we looking at custom JSON deserializers for this purpose?

Also, our clients are .NET initially, so we would be looking for a clean implementation client-side also.

Many thanks

Simon

Answer (score 1):

Given that [SignalR works with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336338/signalr-and-https), you should really consider whether rolling your own solution is worth your time.  If the data is worth protecting, you should be able to justify the expense of an SSL cert.  Also consider the possibility of having your users create their own certs and push them out to the users' machines.

If you try to implement your own encryption and authentication, you'll find that you have to solve a lot of the same problems that SSL solves for you, and they are not easy.  Foremost: how do client and server agree on encryption and authentication keys such that 1) eavesdroppers can't read them and 2) the client can be confident that it is actually communicating with the server and not a malicious impersonator.

If you want to also do this in a browser: any javascript delivered over a non-SSL connection can be modified by an active adversary, which pretty much dooms the implementation of any solution that may work in theory.